# Recursive SELECT with stop condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, recursive-query

My table called **element** looks like this:

```
 id | successor | important
----------------------------
  1 | NULL      | 0
  2 | 4         | 1
  3 | 5         | 0
  4 | 8         | 0
  5 | 6         | 1
  6 | 7         | 0
  7 | NULL      | 0
  8 | 10        | 1
  9 | 10        | 0
 10 | NULL      | 0
```

I start with an element’s ID. Each element may or may not have a succeeding element. So given any element ID I may build a chain of elements from 0..n elements depending on its successors and successor-successors, and so on.

Let’s say my starting ID is 2. This results in the following chain:

```
2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 10
```

Now I want to ask this question: Does a specific element chain contain at least one element where important == 1?

In pseudo-code a function realizing this without unneccessary checks may look like this:

```
boolean chainIsImportant(element)
{
    if (element.important == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    if (element.successor != NULL) {
        return chainIsImportant(element.successor);
    }

    return false;
}
```

I guess this can be realized with `WITH RECURSIVE`, right? How can I stop recursion, once an element with important == 1 was found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is typically done by aggregating the columns in question and adding a condition on the join in the recursive part of the CTE:

```
with recursive all_elements as (
  select id, successor, important, array[important] as important_elements
  from elements
  where successor is null
  union all
  select c.id, c.successor, c.important, p.important_elements||c.important
  from elements c
     join all_elements p on c.successor = p.id
  where 1 <> all(p.important_elements)
)
select *
from all_elements;
```

Note that the condition is "flipped" because the where clause defines those rows that should be included.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE booltree
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , successor INTEGER REFERENCES booltree(id)
        , important Boolean NOT NULL
        );

INSERT INTO booltree(id , successor , important) VALUES
  ( 1, NULL     , False)
  ,(2, 4        , True)
  ,(3, 5        , False)
  ,(4, 8        , False)
  ,(5, 6        , True)
  ,(6, 7        , False)
  ,(7, NULL     , False)
  ,(8, 10       , True)
  ,(9, 10       , False)
 ,(10, NULL     , False)
        ;

-- SELECT * FROM booltree;

WITH RECURSIVE rec AS (
        SELECT id, important
        FROM booltree
        WHERE successor IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT bt.id, GREATEST(rec.important, bt.important) AS important
        FROM booltree bt
        JOIN rec ON bt.successor = rec.id
        )
SELECT id, important
FROM rec
ORDER BY important, id;
```

---

### Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 10
 id | important 
----+-----------
  1 | f
  6 | f
  7 | f
  9 | f
 10 | f
  2 | t
  3 | t
  4 | t
  5 | t
  8 | t
(10 rows)
```

---

Note: IMHO the recursion cannot be stopped once a True importance is found (basically, because LEFT JOINS are not allowed in RECURSIVE UNIONS)
But if you are looking for exactly one given id (or a set of them) then maybe you could use that as the start condition, and search the tree upwards.